# How to write SQL query as below

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table below

[image]

I this table I want to return service 90791 and I want to return the service after that scheduled(H2015).
How can i return it .
starttime and endtime datatype :-char
servicedate data type :-datetime

My current Work:-

```html
    declare @date date ,@starttime time ,@endtime time
        with AllEntityAccess as (select S.serviceCode,S.clientId,S.serviceDate, S.startTime, S.endTime from servicenotes S
            left outer join Clients C on S.clientId = C.clientId where C.clientId = '34'
             )
            select @date=serviceDate,@starttime=startTime ,@endtime=endTime from AllEntityAccess where serviceCode='90791' order by serviceDate desc 

            select serviceDate,startTime,* from servicenotes S
            left outer join Clients C on S.clientId = C.clientId where C.clientId = '34' and serviceDate >= @date and startTime>= @endtime order by S.startTime asc
```

Comment: _last_ - according to joinedDate or other column?

Comment: if i got id 4 row then id 5 also need to return . no need any condition

Comment: Find the ID for the last row for `'x'` and then return rows with an ID greater than or equal to that?

Comment: select top 1* from table where name ='x'  order by joinedDate asc

Comment: [edit] any clarifications directly into the question.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: I Have edited please help me on it

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @last bigint

select top 1 @last=Id
from your_table
where Name='x'
order by Id desc

select top 2 * 
from your_table
where Id >= @last
order by Id asc
```

After edit: Use your queries in "My current work" but change the last to:

```
select top 2 * 
from servicenotes S
where serviceDate>=@date and startTime >= @starttime
order by serviceDate asc, startTime asc
```

Comment: Note that this *assumes* that the ID will the sequential; which is unlikely to be guaranteed.

Comment: Good thought. Was rushing to provide one before closure. Fixed.

Comment: id is not a increment one .

Comment: I made an addition, check it

Answer (score 1):

You can write query like this

```
DECLARE @ID INT = (SELECT Id
   FROM   table
   WHERE  NAME = 'x'
   ORDER  BY joinedDate ASC);--assuming your Id column is int

SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  Id >= ID;
```